# Joining Linq Expressions

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm working with the new EF4 CTP4 although I don't think this has much to do with that.  I am trying to set up a system where I can add auditable fields for our database automatically.  What I'm trying to do is combine the following two expressions

```
a => new
{
    a.CreatedBy,
    a.CreatedTime,
    a.UpdatedBy,
    a.UpdatedTime
}
```

and

```
a => new
{
    a.Id,
    a.Name,


}
```

so the result is equivalant to

```
a => new
{
    a.Id,
    a.Name,
    a.CreatedBy,
    a.CreatedTime,
    a.UpdatedBy,
    a.UpdatedTime
}
```

the result I need to be an Expression<Func<T, object>>.  I've been poking around and tried several things with Expression.Invoke and Expression.And(andalso) and haven't found anything that is working for me.

I'm not quite sure if this is possible but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: EF4 has been officially released as part of .NET 4.0.

Comment: I'm referring to the ADO.Net Feature CTP4 that allows for code first/code only ef development

Comment: You want to have a method with the following signature, am I right?

`Expression<Func<T,AuditObject>> ProjectToAuditObject<T>() where T: IAuditable`

Where `AuditObject` contains required properties (`Id`, `Name` etc).

Comment: not exactly, my T object already has all the properties shown above, object needs to be an anonymous type.  I'm trying to ease adding the mapping to the database for my auditable fields.  If you've seed the ef4 ctp. this is the actual code I'm trying to call

Comment: MapSingleType(AuditablePropertyMap.Map<Team>(a => new
        {
            a.Id,
            a.Name
        })).ToTable("dbo.Teams");

where auditablePropertyMap looks like this

public static Expression<Func<T, object>> Map<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> propertyMap) where T : IAuditable
    {
        Expression<Func<T, object>> expr = (a => new
        {
            a.CreatedBy,
            a.CreatedTime,
            a.UpdatedBy,
            a.UpdatedTime
        });
//what to do here to combine the members of the two expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can simply 'merge' two expressions. But you can use alternate API to create mappings with `EntityMap`.

```
public static class MapBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, object>> GetMap<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> func) where T: IAuditable
    {
        var body = func.Body as NewExpression;

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "o");

        var propertyAccessExprs = new List<Expression>();

        foreach (MemberInfo member in body.Members)
        {
            propertyAccessExprs.Add(Expression.Property(param, member.Name));
        }

        var props = typeof(IAuditable).GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            propertyAccessExprs.Add(Expression.Property(param, prop.Name));
        }

        var columnMappins = new List<Expression>();

        foreach (var access in propertyAccessExprs)
        {
            columnMappins.Add(Expression.Call(typeof(EntityMap).GetMethod("Column", new Type[] {typeof(Object)}), Expression.Convert(access, typeof(Object))));
        }

        var RowExpr = Expression.Call(typeof(EntityMap).GetMethod("Row"), Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(EntityMapColumn), columnMappins));

        var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(RowExpr, param);

        return result;
    }
}
```

The usage is

```
 var builder = new ModelBuilder();
            builder.Entity<SimpleAuditableObject>()
                .HasKey(o => o.Id)
                .MapSingleType(MapBuilder.GetMap<SimpleAuditableObject>(o => new { o.Id, o.Name }));
```

Where

```
public interface IAuditable
{
    int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
    int UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    DateTime UpdatedTime { get; set; }
}

public class SimpleAuditableObject : IAuditable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
    public int UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedTime { get; set; }
}
```

HTH.